# Install Marklogic in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, marklogic

I want to install MarkLogic 9 on my ubuntu machine. I tried following steps from this [doc](http://blog.msbbc.co.uk/2010/04/marklogic-x64-install-on-ubuntu-104.html)

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien --to-deb --verbose MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i marklogic_4.1-6_amd64.deb
sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
```

But when I tried the second one I got an error like this:

```
iama@learner:~$ sudo alien --to-deb --verbose MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64.rpmFile "MarkLogic-9.0-3.1.x86_64.rpm" not found.
```

I don't know how to proceed further. I just wanted to confirm, is there any official documentation to install MarkLogic 9 in ubuntu?

Comment: did you try , `sudo apt-get update` ??

Comment: I didn't tried this . When you want me to try this ??

Comment: after installing alien , run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Yeah i had tried `sudo apt-get update` after installing alien but still facing the same error

Comment: is docker solution for you ?

Comment: Didn&#39;t tried with that . Because I installed ML in Ubuntu

Comment: @Seeker this one works for me https://github.com/alan-johnson/docker-marklogic

Comment: thanks for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is "File Not Found"

- Make sure the rpm file exists in the current directory with read privileges with the name given.
- Make sure sudo is not changing to another directory.
- To be certain, use an absolute file path.

Then, test with `sudo ls -l file..`